# Clipping an image with a preserved aspect ratio using a polygon that doesn't need to have its aspect ratio preserved

Tags: svg

I'd like to create a responsive SVG that consists of an image clipped by a polygon.
The image needs to preserve its aspect ratio and get cropped, while the polygon needs to adapt in width to its container but preserve the same height.
I don't want the whole thing to scale homothetically.

[visual explanation of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL0zc.jpg)

If I set `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the svg, the polygon stretches like planned, but the image is then distorted. I've tried setting `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYmid slice"` to the image, but since the svg is set not to have its aspect ratio preserved it doesn't work as planned.

Here's my current code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1440 810" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <polygon points="0 750,1440 810,1440 60,0 0" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g aria-hidden="true" clip-path="url(#clip)">
        <image
            opacity="0.75"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice"
            xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Monasterio_Khor_Virap%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-01%2C_DD_25.jpg/2880px-Monasterio_Khor_Virap%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-01%2C_DD_25.jpg"
        />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You'd have to write some javascript to scale the polygon and keep its aspect ratio.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear - I don't want to preserve the polygon aspect's ratio. So there's no way to do this that doesn't involve using javascript ?

Comment: You can't preserve the aspect ratio of some things and not others without javascript.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. I've actually resorted to using javascript and it's now having the behavior I want.